# How to correctly import and plot time index format HH:MM:SS.fs into Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, timedelta

I'm new to python and I'm trying to correctly parse a .txt data file into pandas using the time column in the format HH:MM:SS.fs as the index for the dataframe.  An example line of the .txt input file looks like this:

```
00:07:01.250    10.7
```

I've tried the following code using the datetime function, however this adds todays date in addition to importing the timestamp which I don't want to be displayed.  I've also read about the timestamp and timedelta functions but can't see how these would work for this use case.

```py
df = pd.read_csv(f, engine='python', delimiter='\t+', skiprows=23, header=None, usecols=[0,3], index_col=0, names=['Time (HH:MM:SS.fs)', 'NL (%)'], decimal=',')
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Here is the existing import code for the datetime import:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(f, engine='python', delimiter='\t+', skiprows=23, header=None, usecols=[0,3], index_col=0, names=['Time (HH:MM:SS.fs)', 'NL (%)'], decimal=',')
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

An example line of the output looks like this:

```
2019-09-26 00:07:01.250    10.7
```

But want I want is this (without the date):

```
00:07:01.250    10.7
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could read the columns as string, using:

```
df.some_column = df.some_column.astype('str')
```

And then use the "format" argument of "to_datetime". It uses the python "strptime" method to convert a string to a datetime, and that method let you specify the exact format of the converted object, as the following link you show:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

I hope this helps. Wish I have more time to test but unfortunately I don't.